# How to use woocommerce functions in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to use wc_get_product function in a file in a wordpress plugin but when I call this function I have Call to undefined function wc_get_product() error.
WooCommerce plugin installed and actice in my wordpress

Answer (score 4):

Probably you call wc functions before they are loaded. Try this:

```
/**
* Check if WooCommerce is active
**/
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    // Put your plugin code here

    // If you want use WooCommerce functions, do that after WooCommerce is loaded
    add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'my_function_with_wc_functions' );        
}

function my_function_with_wc_functions() {

    $product = wc_get_product();

}
```

Great stuff to read:

- [Creating a plugin for WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/)
- [WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

Comment: `wc_get_product()` returns fals? Maybe you have to provide the right arguments. But the function is defined now?

Comment: Hooking into woocommerce_loaded, `wc_get_products` is defined now but returns an empty array. When called in a template, it returns all my products. I simply hook into `wp_loaded` now and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product = WC_Product($product_id);
$product->wc_get_product();
```

Comment: seems that woocommerce is not included in part of wp.
Before apply this
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php' );

Comment: ^^ DON'T do this. Make sure your actions and filters are called correctly via your plugins and/or `functions.php` file; don't make hacky calls to force-include plugin files directly.